In the kinematic equations, how is that possible while deriving an equation?
We have this kinematic equation:
$$x_f = x_i + v_it + \frac{1}{2} at^2.$$
Now, I do not have any problem with this equation, but where I have a problem with is the way we derived this equation.
We derived this equation from the following equations:

Eq. 1: $v = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$ for $a = 0$ (no acceleration)

Eq. 2: $v = \frac{v_f + v_i}{2}$ for $a = \text{const}$ (there is a constant acceleration)

Eq. 3: $a = \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$


My focus is not on the third equation, but the first and second equations.
In this first step we say that Eq. 1 and Eq. 2 are equal, so we get the following equation:
$$\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{v_f + v_i}{2}$$
The thing that is mind-boggling to me here is how we could make an equation (Eq. 1) that deals with acceleration as if it equals zero (meaning there is absolutely no acceleration), and an equation that has acceleration as constant (meaning there is acceleration) be equal.
How could we make Eq. 1 and Eq. 2 equal if there is a contradiction with the acceleration part?


Solve $x'' = a_{0}$ by integrating

I don't understand what you're trying to ask. As you rightfully said, the two expressions have different assumptions. By equating them, the resultant will only hold under the intersection of both assumptions (zero acceleration for eq.1 and constant acceleration for eq.2), which is zero acceleration. Then the RHS is $v=v$ which says nothing.

Sorry if this turns out as an answer-in-comment, but $0$ is definitely a constant, too.

It is indeed mindboggling.  What you are digging at is the reason Newton has to invent calculus to define this sort of motion.  Calculus deals with the infinitesimal time slices where acceleration doesn't matter.  It's a great topic, but there's lots of equations that require a bit of faith until one learns the calculus behind them.

With might be confusing you is not the math (apparently), but the hypothesis underlying each equation. In fact, both equations are true definitions of average velocity, but let's take a look on both equations to understand what is happening.
The equation one
\begin{equation}
v = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}
is a good definition of average velocity no matter you have or not acceleration. When $a=0$, this turns to be the real velocity of the system. The difference for cases with non zero acceleration is that sometimes, when we consider big space and time intervals, the mean velocity calculated this way can poorly represent what happened in the interval. For example, imagine a car travelling between two cities. The car accelerate and brakes a lot of times for many reasons. You can calculate the average velocity of the trip by the distance between two cities $\Delta x$ and the time of travel $\Delta t$, but if you do this, sometimes you get a lower velocity than the velocity of the car on the majority part of the trip (try this next time you make a trip between two cities).
Equation two
\begin{equation}
v = \frac{v_f + v_i}{2}
\end{equation}
Is what we call a mean quantity. It is the mathematical definition of arithmetic mean of a quantity (there is a lot of other types of mean values). This can also be used to represent the average velocity, but it is not necessarily equal equation one. Of course if the acceleration is zero, initial and final velocities will be the same and this quantity will be equal to the real velocity. It means that with no acceleration, both definitions are equal
\begin{equation}
v = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{v_f + v_i}{2} = v_{real} \quad (a=0)
\end{equation}
Now, let's see what happens with both definitions when we have constant acceleration. By equation one and considering $x_f =x_i + v_it + at^2/2$,
\begin{equation}
v_{avg}^{(1)} = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = v_i + \frac{at}{2}, \quad (a \text{ constant})
\end{equation}
Note that Im considering the space interval between fixed $x_f$ and $x_i$ and $0,t$ as time interval. Now, whe know also that
\begin{equation}
v_f = v_i + at
\end{equation}
So by equation 2
\begin{equation}
v_{avg}^{(2)} = \frac{v_f+v_i}{2} = v_i + \frac{at}{2}
\end{equation}
So for constant acceleration, we verified that both equations also are equal. However, we cannot say that both are equal the real velocity, since the velocity will not be a number, but a function in time. It means we will have a different value of velocity at a time.
